# Getting 001270 error : Consolidating the data failed while publishing as map service in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, sql-server, map-service, error-001270

I am getting an error "001270  error" .

I am inserting table for sql-server database and joining few records to polygon layer

also I have lat,Lon data in few tables so I am displaying data using "Display x,y values" and publishing all data into arcgis server 10.1 (using ArcGIs Desktop 10.1)

While publishing I was getting above error..

also my database & folders are registered in ArcGIS Server (through ArcCatalog I did this)

I found following article which explain that its bug  Link : http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDgzMjc5 ..but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [001270 : Consolidating the data failed.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000002r001270) documentation might help you fix the issue.